# Произведение элементов массива по индексам

Tags: java, массивы

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class task54 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите количество элементов массива");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        Random m = new Random();
        int mas[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Случайный массив=");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            mas[i] = m.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println(mas[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

В этом массиве нужно найти произведение элементов, чей индекс кратен 3. Каким образом это легче всего сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легче всего это сделать так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Введите количество элементов массива: ");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();
    Random m = new Random();
    int mas[] = new int[n];
    System.out.print("Случайный массив: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        mas[i] = m.nextInt(100);
        System.out.print(mas[i] + " ");
    }
    // Перемножаем элементы массива с индексом, кратным трем.
    // Под произведение готовим переменную work
    long work = 1;
    // Формирует цикл начинающийся с индекса 3
    // и в каждой итерации добавляем 3 к индексу
    for (int i = 3; i < n; i += 3) {
        work *= mas[i]; // в цикле накапливаем произведение
    }
    System.out.println("\nПроизведение элементов массива " +
            "с индексом кратным трем: " + work);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее короткое решение с использованием стримов. 
Я бы сделал примерно так

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Task54{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите количество элементов массива");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int mas[] = createRandomArray(s.nextInt());
        int result = calculate(mas, 3);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mas));
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static int calculate(int[] array, int indexMultiplicity) {
        return IntStream.range(1, array.length)
                .filter(i->i%indexMultiplicity==0)
                .reduce(1,(a,b)->a*array[b]);
    }

    private static int[] createRandomArray(int capacity) {
        final Random m = new Random();
        int mas[] = new int[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) mas[i] = m.nextInt(100);
        return mas;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

int product = IntStream
        // обходим индексы массива
        .range(0, arr.length)
        // индекс кратен 3
        .filter(i -> i % 3 == 0)
        // берем элементы по индексу
        .map(i -> arr[i])
        // перемножаем
        .reduce((e1, e2) -> e1 * e2)
        // получам значение
        .getAsInt();

// вывод
System.out.println(product); // 28
```